# Why do I need to type `source/.rvm/scripts/rvm` when I use Ruby?

Tags: ruby, installation

When I use Ruby, I have to type on my terminal:

```
source/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Why cannot it be automatically done? Can you help me to make it automatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this like:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in `.profile` file or `.bashrc` located in your root directory (`~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`)

This will load up rvm into a bash session so you don't have to manually type it every time.